# The background element is static, when scrolling the content of the box

Tags: javascript, html

After the pop-up box pops up in the web, when I want to scroll the content of the pop-up box, the background element cannot scroll. After closing the pop-up box, the position of the background element will remain unchanged. Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Without code its hard to tell what you have done wrong. If you want help from community show efforts what you have tried so far. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use js to dynamically set the style of the pageview package of the body and the child elements of the body. For example:

Html:

```
<body>
<div class="pageview"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('#dlg_btn__open').click(function () {
    // ...something else
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('body').css({ height: '100%', overflowY: 'hidden' }); // Fix background
    $('.pageview').css({ position: 'fixed', top: (-1 * st) + 'px' }); // Fix background
});
$('#dlg_btn__close').click(function () {
    // ...something else
    var st = $('.pageview').css('top').replace('-', '').replace('px', '');
    $('body').css({ height: 'auto', overflowY: 'visible' });// Cancel fixed background
    $('.pageview').css({ position: 'relative', top: 0 });// Cancel fixed background
    window.scrollTo(0, st);// Roll to original position
});
```